# How to get friends names from the table User consisting of friends array having object Id's of the users which are friend using Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mern

I have a model called User. User consist of friends array

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    password:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
    }, 
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    avatar: {
        type: String
    },

    friends: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'User'
        }
    ]
    
}, {
    timestamps: true
});

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

I want to populate friends of the user so that I can show the names of the friends. I am using this code to populate

```
// req.user is the logged in user and I have checked its id that it is correct
 
const friends = await users.find({'_id':req.user._id})
        .populate("friends").exec();
        console.log(friends);
```

but I am getting the details of req.user (logged in user) itself and not the details of friends. Please help me

Comment: Your model has `friends` as an array of `ObjectId`, which is fine -- but your `find` expression will not give you details.  You need to use `$lookup` or `$graphLookup` in the aggregation framework.

Comment: Instead of `users.find`, if you use `users.findOne`, does it work then?